# Android: Method in Fragment Lifecycle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle

I'm looking for a method in the Fragment Lifecycle, but I'm not sure which one.

Here's my situation: I've got a Fragment inside a ViewPager. The Fragment displays a List with some information. I fill the list in the Fragment's `onCreateView()`. When the user opens a different Activity (settings in this case) and changes some settings, the information that the List in the Fragment has to show, changes. When the user returns to the Fragment using the Back-button, the `onCreateView()` isn't re-called, so the information in the List isn't updated.

My question is: The `onCreateView()`-method isn't called when the user returns to the fragment form a different Activity, but which method is called here? I need to know this because then I can fill the List in that method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about `onResume`?

Comment: @vmironov Is `onResume()` also called the first time the Fragment is created or only when the user returns?

Comment: yes, it's called when the Fragment is created as well

Comment: Okay, thanks, that one should work then. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onResume()` is the simple answer, called when user comes back. for more details refer lifecycle here [FragmentLifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 2):

Important and non-obvious point it that Fragment's onCreateView() being called not only in case you selected Tab with this Fragment. So **don't rely on onCreateView() of Fragment when using ViewPager()**. When You select the Tab, Android creates sible views (caches them) or makes something similar.

You should call your update method when user selects proper Tab in ViewPager (don't remember exactly, but hope it helps).

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but for now, I only call `findViewById()`'s in onCreateView(), so I bet that won't be a problem, will it?

Comment: With findViewById() - no problems possible as You just create reference to some view. Unexpected behaivor could occur if You put some UI refresh or, especially, time consuming logic, because it could be runned earlier than You expect.